# Problems Generating A Math.random Number, Either 0 or 1

Tags: java, random

I want a random number, either 0 or 1 and then that will be returned to main() as in my code below.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Exercise8Lab7 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int numFlips = 0;
        int heads = 0;
        int tails = 0;
        String answer;


        System.out.print("Please Enter The Number Of Coin Tosses You Want: ");
        numFlips = input.nextInt();

        for(int x = 1;x <= numFlips; x++){
            if(coinToss() == 1){
                answer = "Tails";
                tails++;
            }
            else{
                answer = "Heads";
                heads++;
            }
            System.out.print("\nCoin Toss " + x + ": " + answer);
        }
        System.out.println("\n\n====== Overall Results ======" +
        "\nPercentage Of Heads: " + (heads/numFlips)*100 + "\nPercentage Of Tails: " + (tails/numFlips)*100);
    }

    public static int coinToss(){
        double rAsFloat = 1 * (2 + Math.random( ) );
        int r = (int)rAsFloat;
        return r;
    }
}
```

Many solutions had been suggested to use the util.Random option which I have done and works perfectly but I want to sort out why I can't get this to work. Obviously I want the number to be an int myself so I convert it to an int after the random number has been generated. But no matter what I add or multiply the Math.random() by, it will always all either be Heads or all either be Tails. Never mixed.

Comment: Well, writing `1 *` should have been a clue that you didn't do it right, because multiplying anything by 1 doesn't accomplish a whole lot.

Comment: `Random` has a `.nextInt()` version taking an upper bound. Otherwise, well, just generate a random int and do `% 2` on it.

Comment: because `Math.random() + 2` generates a random number between 2.0 and 2.9. Nothing in this range will ever be equal to 1. If you are only interested in 0 or 1 use `Math.round(Math.random())`

Comment: Thanks to everyone who answered! I just multiplied the Math.random() by 2 and now it's giving me random answers for Heads and Tails. Problem now is the percentage for Heads and percentage for Tails in the last print statement is not working at all, they are always both = 0...

Answer (score 20):

Try this) It will generate number **0** or **1**

```
 Math.round( Math.random() )  ;
```

Comment: Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged.

Comment: This will generate double value. Example: 1.0

Answer (score 19):

You could use boolean values of 0 or 1 based on value of `Math.random()` as a double between 0.0 and 1.0 and make the random generator much simpler. And you can get rid completely of the `coinToss()` method.

```
if(Math.random() < 0.5) {
    answer = "Tails";
    tails++;
}
```

Remove the coin toss method and replace the first conditional with the code above.

`Math.random();` by itself will return a value between 0.0 and less than 1.0. If the value is in the lower half, [0.0, 0.5), then it has the same probability of being in the upper half, [0.5, 1.0). Therefore you can set any value in the lower half as true and upper as false.

Answer (score 10):

Wierd that no one is using a modulo division for the random number.
This is the simplest implementation you can get:

```
Random rand = new Random();
int randomValue = rand.nextInt() % 2;
```

Comment: random number can be negative, so the output is not necessary either 0 and 1.

Answer (score 5):

Math.round(Math.random()) will return either 0.0 and 1.0. Since both these values are well within the limits of int range they can be casted to int.

```
public static int coinToss(){
    return (int)Math.round(Math.random());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`Math.random()` returns a random float in the range [0.0,1.0)--that means the result can be anything from 0 up to *but not including* 1.0.

Your code

```
double rAsFloat = 1 * (2 + Math.random( ) );
```

will take this number in the [0.0,1.0) range; adding 2 to it gives you a number in the [2.0,3.0) range; multiplying it by 1 does nothing useful; then, when you truncate it to an integer, the result is always 2.

To get integers from this kind of random function, you need to figure out how many different integers you could return, then multiply your random number by that.  If you want a "0 or 1" answer, your range is 2 different integers, so multiply `Math.random()` by 2:

```
double rAsFloat = 2 * Math.random();
```

This gives you a random number in the range [0.0,2.0), which can then be 0 or 1 when you truncate to an integer with `(int)`.  If, instead, you wanted something that returns 1 or 2, for example, you'd just add 1 to it:

```
double rAsFloat = 1 + 2 * Math.random();
```

I think you've already figured out that the `Random` class gives you what you want a lot more easily.  I've decided to explain all this anyway, because someday you might work on a legacy system in some old language where you really do need to work with a [0.0,1.0) random value.  (OK, maybe that's not too likely any more, but who knows.)

Answer (score 3):

(int)(Math.random()*2) also works fine in this case

Comment: why this answer is having downvote. That is the best (if not the best the most widely spread) answer known for decades.

Answer (score 2):

its not working because of the integer math you are using, the call to 2+ Math.Random is pretty much always giving you a answer between 0.0 and 1.0.

so assuming that you recieve 0.25 as your result your maths is as follows

```
double d = 1* (2 + 0.25); // (result = 2
```

Then  you are checking to see if your result == 1 ( which it never will. )

A better result would be to declare java.util.Random as a class variable and call random.nextBoolean() and simply perform your heads/tails calculation on that.

If you were to continue to use Math.random() and lets say

```
return Math.random() < 0.5
```

Your results would be ever so slightly skewed due to the fact that Math.random() cannot return 1.0, due to the fact that the java API specification states:

"Returns a double value with a positive sign, greater than or equal to 0.0 and less than 1.0."

Comment: I don't think the results would be skewed.  If my understanding is correct, the number of possible values that `Math.random()` could return that are < 0.5 is **exactly** equal to the number of possible values that are >= 0.5.  I'd have to study the algorithm to be 100% certain, though.

Comment: This is actually an awesome question, more so than a comment.
lets see if I can fit this into the amount of space for a comment (and my apologies for the lack of formatting. ) 

Previous versions of java had a massive bias towards zero ( the function was: ((((long)next(27) << 27) + next(27)) / (double)(1L << 54);)

, so in later versions they reduced the bias by a slight change in maths ((((long)(next(26)) << 27) + next(27)) / (double)(1L << 53);) ... So by reducing the size of the first random number of bits (but maintaining the size of the shift) they introduce a ever so slight bias -cont-

Comment: at 134217728, In the original code there was a bias of the lowest bit in the internal mantissa of the floating point number being 0 (it was 3 times as likely than not), so with this 'minor' change they were able to remove that in exchange for having a slight bias towards the just above the center, which is better than having a bias at a given fixed bit. The next method also has its own internal bias which compounds this.. If you check the javadoc in detail it should note that the output is "approximately" uniform, there are 2 methods of proving this, the first simply brute forcing the -cont-

Comment: 2 calls to next with 2 for loops and returning a list of all of the results (which will be extremely time consuming) but will allow you to then draw a histogram of results.

Otherwise if lazy (and time constrained. ) create a loop to run the 'coin flip' algorithm and count the results, you should notice a 'skew' in the ratio between true and false which grows over time.

Comment: Very interesting!  I'll have to look into this further, when I can find the time (wishful thinking...).

Answer (score 2):

The problem can be translated to boolean generation as follow :

```
public static byte get0Or1 {

Random random = new Random();
boolean res=   random.nextBoolean();

if(res)return 1;
else return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here it the easiest way I found without using java.util.Random.

> Blockquote

```
Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

System.out.println("Please enter 0 for heads or 1 for tails");

int integer = input.nextInt();

input.close();

int random = (int) (Math.random() + 0.5);

if (random == integer) {
    System.out.println("correct");
}
else {
    System.out.println("incorrect");
}
System.out.println(random);
```

This will take a random double from (0 to .99) and add .5 to make it (.5 to 1.49). It will also cast it to an int, which will make it (0 to 1). The last line is for testing.

Answer (score 0):

```
 for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
System.out.println(((int)(i*Math.random())%2)); 
    }
```

use mod it will help you!

Answer (score 0):

One more variant

```
rand.nextInt(2);
```

As it described in [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29) it will return random int value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive)